# Test desktop app with Retina images without Retina display

Tags: objective-c, macos, retina-display

I need to add in to my desktop app Retina images. I know how to add it but I have issue with testing it, because my MacBook dosen't has Retina display.
So, is there are some solutions how test retina images without Retina display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple provides a set of tools to do so. 
You will find it all there: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Testing/Testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH6-SW1